# Convert a shell script to python

Tags: python, shell

I have a shell script, which I want to convert into python. Can somebody please help.

Please find below the sample shell script.

```
A='Abdc12nklskfdfuldfdfdg_APPID'
B='1000000-0000-444g-sdsg-ab12ehiy8e8'
z=`echo -n "$A:$B" | base64 -w 0`
echo $z
```

Comment: what does the shell script do? pls explain

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
import base64

A = 'Abdc12nklskfdfuldfdfdg_APPID'
B = '1000000-0000-444g-sdsg-ab12ehiy8e8'
A_B = A + ':' + B
Z = base64.b64encode(bytes(A_B, 'utf-8'))
print(Z)
```

output

```
b'QWJkYzEybmtsc2tmZGZ1bGRmZGZkZ19BUFBJRDoxMDAwMDAwLTAwMDAtNDQ0Zy1zZHNnLWFiMTJlaGl5OGU4'
```